# How can I not display a page if a user is not logged in with PHP?

Tags: php, html, authentication

I want to hide everything on a page when a user is not logged in with PHP.

Currently, I redirect the user if they are not logged in, but in case people are trying to get around the redirect, I want to make sure none of the content is displayed.

I understand that you could always use...

```
// Pseudo-code

if(!logged in){
    header("Location: login.php");
}else{
    echo "<html>...the whole page";
}
```

But this is too hard to maintain because I have to escape all quotes and code editors don't display is too well.

What can I use to just stop displaying any code if the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP you could use this in the beginning of the file you'd like to hide from visitors who are not logged in:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) // The exact conditional depends on your login-system implementation
{
    header('Location: login.php'); // Instructs the visitor's browser to redirect
    exit; // <-- What you want. Prevents further code from being executed, works as a security measure.
}
```

Or in your pseudo-code:

```
if(!logged in)
    exit;
```